# Change background url dynamically in paper-scroll-header-panel

Tags: javascript, html, css, polymer-1.0

So I have this style that when the header condenses it change its background into red and when the header is at its full size it display a backgroun

```
paper-scroll-header-panel {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: var(--paper-grey-100);

    --paper-scroll-header-panel-full-header: {
      background-image: url(images/bg1.jpg);
    }

    --paper-scroll-header-panel-condensed-header: {
      background-color: var(--paper-red-700);
    }
  }
```

The problem is I load the image background url dynamically.
What is the way to set '--paper-scroll-header-panel-condensed-header' background-image using javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `css3 variables` and `updateStyles` API to dynamically load the value of any css property.

```html
<base href="https://polygit.org/components/">
<script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
<link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">
<dom-module id="variable-background">
  <template>
    <style>
      :host {
        --image-url: url(http://www.freedigitalphotos.net/images/img/homepage/87357.jpg);
        background-image: var(--image-url);
        display: block;
        height: 100px;
      }
    </style>
    <div on-tap='changeBackground'>Tap me</div>
  </template>
</dom-module>
<script>
  Polymer({
    is: 'variable-background',
    changeBackground: function() {
      var obj = {
        '--image-url': 'url(http://mediafiles.allaboutsymbian.com/808/zeiss/g.jpg)'
      };
      this.updateStyles(obj);
    }
  })
</script>


<variable-background></variable-background>
```

Comment: Than you so much, this changed my process on how to deal with css styles over my project. It made my day @a1626 Problem solved!